# Get all content from a folder with subfolder copied to another directory with bash

Tags: bash

I have a directory that has many folders in it that have sub folders again and then there are some files. Can I write a bash script that copies all the files from the given directory into one single folder? So that I do not have to navigate through ever single folder and copy the content to another folder.

Comment: Only the files or do you want to copy the directory structure?

Comment: I only need the files

Comment: did you try looking into the -R flag of cp?

Comment: @alDiablo yeah, but cp -r also copies the folder. I only want the files that are inside the folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the topmost dir under which you want the files to be copied:

```
find . -type f -exec cp {} /some/new/location \;
```

Finds all the normal files and then copies them to `/some/new/location`

Comment: small hint, `+` at the end might just be a bit more helpful to launch less cp.

Answer (score 0):

You could use find to list all files inside the folder:

```
find ./source -type f
```

and then use the output as argument for cp, it would look like this:

```
cp $(find ./source -type f) destination
```

There would be problem if there are some files within the original directory tree with conflicting name. In that case cp would refuse to copy additional files with the same name with error like:

> cp: will not overwrite just-created `destination/t22' with`./source/test/t2/t22'

To make copies of files with same name, you can use backup option, like this:

```
cp --backup=numbered $(find ./source -type f) destination
```

If you want to see what is happening use -v (verbose) option

```
cp -v --backup=numbered $(find ./source -type f) destination
```